# How can I make a shader that renders only the scene's skybox?

Tags: unity, shaders

I am trying to replicate the following image:

[image]

There are a few ways about doing this that involve camera stacking, layers, etc. Is it possible to create a shader that will *only* render the skybox?

Comment: Sure. Make an unlit shader that takes a skybox cubemap, and samples it according to the view direction. How have you tried implementing this so far?